# Preventing a game object that has faded out from colliding with other game objects

Tags: unity

I have the following cycle for fading sprites in and out

fade out (1 second) -> delay (2 seconds)-> fade in -> delay (2 seconds)

Please see my code below:

```
IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration) {

    Color color = material.color;
    float startOpacity = color.a;

    float t = 0;

    while(t < duration) {
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

        color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);
        material.color = color;
        yield return null;
    }
}    


IEnumerator EnemyCycle()
{

    while (isRepeating)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

            var _myMaterial = enemies [j].GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(_myMaterial, 0f, 1f));
            enemies [j].GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ().enabled = false;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);

        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

            enemies [j].GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ().enabled = true;
            var _myMaterial = enemies [j].GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(_myMaterial, 1f, 1f));
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);

    }
}
```

The above code cycle works when I am not disabling and enabling the colliders. i.e., without the following lines of code:

```
enemies [j].GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ().enabled = false;
enemies [j].GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ().enabled = true;
```

But when I place the two lines (as I've done in the above code), the enemy game objects don't follow the fade in and out cycle, mostly they don't even fade out. 
I really need to be able to prevent the enemies from colliding with other game objects when I have faded them out during my fade in and out cycle. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I am still trying to figure this out. Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code, it's working here for me.
A few things

- Maybe there is another object interacting with this behaviour?
- Did you set the colliders?
- Are you getting any errors?
- There's a plats [j].GetComponent ().enabled = true;
- Also, how did u define the isRepeating variable? Is the value set to true?
- did you mean 'enemies' instead of plats ?

  Sorry, i cannot comment, i dont have 50 reputation..

Comment: I was setting a CircleCollider instead of a BoxCollider. Thanks

Comment: Now you got the reputation to comment :D.